# Incorrect file conversion to byte array

Tags: c#, php, arrays, image, xamarin

I'm trying to pick an image from device gallery and upload it to remote server converting the image to byte array and send it with php script.

The upload script seems work because the file appear in the server directory but when I open the page return an error like "cannot open image because it contains errors".

**MyPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pickPhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
                return;
            }
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (file == null)
                return;

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
              {
                  var stream = file.GetStream();
                  return stream;
              });

            //ADD THIS
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            await httpClient.PostAsync("http://mysite.altervista.org/path/upload_file.php?image=", new StreamContent(file.GetStream()));//I tried also without ?image= 

            //byte[] abyte = ByteArrayFromFile(file_tmp.GetStream());
            //await sendImage(abyte);
        };
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> sendImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mysite.altervista.org/");
        StringContent str = new StringContent("image="+byteArray.GetValue(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://mysite/upload_file.php"), str);
        var placesJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RESPONSE: " + placesJson);
        return response;
    }

    public static byte[] ByteArrayFromFile(Stream location)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(location))
        {
            var bytes = default(byte[]);
            using (var memstream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                streamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memstream);
                bytes = memstream.ToArray();
                return bytes;
            }
        }
    }
```

**upload_file.php**

```
<?php
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    $filename = "myimg.jpg";
    //$binary=base64_decode($base); //commented this
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen($filename, 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $base); //changed $binary to $base
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
?>
```

Comment: a) you cannot use a GET to send a byte[] of an image, it's too big.  Use a POST instead  b) your PHP assume the data is base64 encoded, but your client side code is just posting the raw byte[]

Comment: @Jason i've updated question code, it still doesn't work

Comment: Your content type is not a valid MIME type.  The MIME type should be "image/whatever-the-mime-type-of-your-image-data-is".  Also PHP isn't well suited to manipulating raw binary data, it doesn't have a byte type, only signed integers which are either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the underlying hardware

Comment: @GordonM I've setted `Content-Type: image/png` but still doesn't work. I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Using a GET request to send files is not the way to go about this.

Use this instead:

```
 httpClient.PostAsync("url.com", new StreamContent(stream));
```

Comment: I tried to do this and the advice by @Jason about the submission of raw value as you can see in the updated question. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've done another update, but still doesn't work... you have other suggestions ?